# What are the item stats for a formula book?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment

I've checked the PFSRD, but I can't find an item description for an alchemist or investigator's formula book. Should I use a wizard's spellbook as a template, or is there somthing else that I missed that would work better?

Particularly, how much does the book weigh? What does it cost? How many pages does it have? How much space does a single formula take up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find information about Formula Books on the [Pathfinder PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/gear/toolsAndSkillKits.html).

To answer your questions, the formula book weighs 3 lbs, costs 15 gp and has 100 pages and formulas take up 1 page per spell level. It even notes that it follows the same rules as a spellbook.

Comment: Yep. The only difference from a spellbook is that wizards can't copy from a formula book (though alchemists can copy from a spellbook).